# Conditional formatting on Shopify snippet based on template file

Tags: conditional-statements, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have a block in my Shopify product page that states product availability, in a snippet called `product-page-1-description.liquid`, which passes up a few files to get to `product-template.liquid`. My problem is that gift-cards also uses this file to display product information, and I need to remove/hide the availability line for them in particular.

Here's my question: can I run a liquid conditional to show/hide this block based on the template (gift-card/product) calling the file? Just creating an entirely new snippet seems wasteful. Thanks!

```
#product-page-1-description.liquid

 {%- if item.show_product_main_info -%}
  <div class="tt-add-info">
    <ul>
      {%- if item.show_quantity -%}
      <li class="availability">
        <span>{{ 'products.product.availability' | t }}</span>
        {% if product.available %}
        <span class="stock_quantity hide"></span> <span class="in_stock hide">{{ 'products.product.in_stock' | t }}</span> <span class="many_in_stock hide">{{ 'products.product.many_in_stock' | t }}</span> <span class="sold_out hide">{{ "products.product.sold_out" | t }}</span> <span class="continue_out hide">{{ "products.product.purchase_when_out_of_stock" | t }}</span>
        {% else %}
        <span class="sold_out">{{ "products.product.sold_out" | t }}</span>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {%- endif -%}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you can check with this either using `product.type` or simply add a custom tag to determine which product is currently.

Comment: or check something like this also `{% if template contains 'gift_card' %}{% endif %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `product-page-1-description.liquid` from `templates/gift_card.liquid`  add a variable call `giftCard`

`{% include 'product-page-1-description.liquid', giftCard: true %}`

and when in show availability, check for condition

```
 {%- if item.show_product_main_info -%}
      <div class="tt-add-info">
        <ul>
          {% unless giftCard %}
              {%- if item.show_quantity -%}
              <li class="availability">
                <span>{{ 'products.product.availability' | t }}</span>
                {% if product.available %}
                <span class="stock_quantity hide"></span> <span class="in_stock hide">{{ 'products.product.in_stock' | t }}</span> <span class="many_in_stock hide">{{ 'products.product.many_in_stock' | t }}</span> <span class="sold_out hide">{{ "products.product.sold_out" | t }}</span> <span class="continue_out hide">{{ "products.product.purchase_when_out_of_stock" | t }}</span>
                {% else %}
                <span class="sold_out">{{ "products.product.sold_out" | t }}</span>
                {% endif %}
              </li>
              {%- endif -%}
            {% endunless %}
        </ul>
      </div>
```